# Dagger throws IllegalStateException while injecting nested dependency

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I want to inject into Activity object that has nested dependency. All dependencies are managed by Dagger module.

I've tried to do it for three different way. For me the best is method third, which actually throws me an error, which I don't fully understand.

Can you explain me why third method isn't working?

```
public class Bar {
    public void bar() {
        Log.i("Bar", "bar");
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Inject
    Foo foo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ObjectGraph.create(new MainModule()).inject(this);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    void onButtonClick() {
        foo.foo();
    }
}
```

**First method is working - Foo is implementation of an interface:**

```
public interface IFoo {
    public void foo();
}

public class Foo implements IFoo{

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        bar.bar();
    }
}

@Module(injects = MainActivity.class, library = true)
public class MainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Bar provideBar() {
        return new Bar();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    IFoo provideFoo(Foo foo) {
        return foo;
    }

}
```

**Second method is working - Foo is normal class but module doesn't contains it:**

```
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

    public void foo() {
        bar.bar();
    }
}

@Module(injects = MainActivity.class)
public class MainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Bar provideBar() {
        return new Bar();
    }

}
```

**Third method throws an error - Foo is normal class and module contains it:**

```
Error:(12, 8) error: Unknown error java.lang.IllegalStateException thrown by javac in graph validation: Dependency cycle:
0. foo.Foo bound by @Singleton/ProvidesBinding[key=foo.Foo method=foo.MainModule.provideFoo()
0. foo.Foo

public class Foo {

    @Inject
    Bar bar;

    public void foo() {
        bar.bar();
    }
}

@Module(injects = MainActivity.class, library = true)
public class MainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Bar provideBar() {
        return new Bar();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Foo provideFoo(Foo foo) {
        return foo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This provider method creates a cycle:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Foo provideFoo(Foo foo) {
    return foo;
}
```

You need an instance of `Foo` to create an instance of `Foo`, so you can never obtain an instance.

Proposed solution:

```
public class Foo {

    private final Bar bar;

    @Inject
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void foo() {
        bar.bar();
    }
}

@Module(injects = MainActivity.class, library = true)
public class MainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Bar provideBar() {
        return new Bar();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Foo provideFoo(Bar bar) {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, but when Foo is implementation of IFoo (second method) dagger is able to create new instance. What is difference where there is no interface?

Comment: @lusiak, Foo and IFoo are different types in the end. Dagger can provide an instance of Foo without thinking of it as an instance of IFoo. Here you don't have a provider for Foo, therefore Dagger creates it using default strategy; in third case you have a provider for Foo which Dagger will use to give you an instance of Foo - and will run into a cycle

Comment: I think I understand now. Dagger is not so easy after all. Thanks.

Comment: @lusiak, Please check the edit, I think this should work better in your case

Comment: Yes, I think that solution is the best from all.